# Angular read data from server (Laravel backend)

Tags: angular, laravel, service

Sorry if there was a similar question but I read more of answers and didn't find answer on my question.
So...here is the problem:

This is my JSON response:

```
[
 {"id":1,"text":"test","image":""},
 {"id":2,"text":"test","image":""},
 {"id":3,"text":"tabl","image":"image1.jpg"}
]
```

And this is how looks like my **service** in angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestData } from './testdata';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestserviceService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { 
  }
  findAll():Observable<TestData[]> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
      }),
      responseType: 'text' as 'json'  
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<TestData[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/testData', httpOptions );
  }
}
```

This is my method in **component:**

```
  public findAlldatas(){
    this.testDataService.findAll()
    .subscribe(data => this.testData = data )
  }
```

Here is how I try to write data in HTML:

```
    <button (click)="findAlldatas()">test service</button>    
    <div *ngFor="let cityDetailss of testData">
      <li>{{cityDetailss.id}}</li>
    </div>
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    [{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;image&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;image&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;tabl&quot;,&quot;image&quot;:&quot;sarajevo1.jpg&quot;}]
    
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:20725)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:4483)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24506)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CityDetailComponent.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
```

Can somebody, please, help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It appears that the result that you are actually getting from the api call is HTML, not JSON. The error message is showing you that response, and complaining that the HTML string is not a array or an iterable.

Comment: I would suggest testing your Laravel service by hitting it from Postman or any other tool and check your response. Coz it seems like, it's returning HTML instead of JSON. And moreover, for reading JSON response, you need not configure responseType manually. It's already defaulted to "json"

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much on your answers, yes..it was my mistake the results were HTML so I fixed it but now I get this error in console:



ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"id":1,"text":"test","image":""},{"id":2,"text":"test","image":""},{"id":3,"text":"tabl","image":"image1.jpg"}]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed